# Dynamic iframe resize woes in google chrome

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome

I seem to be having an iFrame resize issue with Google Chrome.

```
> <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function resizeIframe(obj)

 {
   obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';


     }
 </script>

<
```

That's in my header.

```
> <iframe id="content" name="content" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="950px" src="html/index2.html" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe> <
```

That is my iframe script.

So what I'm trying to do is to resize the iFrame dynamically per page content, and it works flawlessly in Firefox & IE, but not Chrome. What gives? Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a [bug with chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=34224). Why can't you use clientHeight for now instead of scrollHeight?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Tried that and it didn't work in chrome, yet again. I'm a bit of a noob with it comes to javascript and im trying to use a setTimeout because my recent research suggests something about chrome loading the javascript too fast? I can't seem to get the setTimeout to work!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<iframe src="your url" width="your widthpx" height="your heightpx"></iframe>
```